# Angular CLI Error: Port 80 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: angular-cli

When trying to build the Angular application and starts a web server using the command (os: Ubuntu):

```
ng serve --port 80
```

The following error shown:

> Port 80 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is misleading. Actually, ports below 1048 needs root privileges.

On Linux (like Ubuntu), one of the ways to be able to use port 80, is to use **sudo** as follows:

```
sudo ng serve --port 80
```